# Post added via wp_insert_post with category doesn't show in category listing

Tags: plugin-development

I've created a plugin that auto creates a post and attaches a category to it, which is then hidden from the main blog and only shows in the category listing...

I can successfully add a new post via wp_insert_post with all the correct params and once the post_id is returned I'm calling wp_set_object_terms with the category I want that post to be included under.

I can confirm that the post is created, and the post has the correct category. However, if I visit the category listing for that particular cat, I see all the previous posts but not the dynamically created one. If I manually add a new post and select the same category, it does display in the list.

I haven't found anything regarding why this is happening... Has anyone else run into this issue? Everything seems to be working fine, except with the category listing...

(Edited to add code sample)

```
    $new_post = array(
    'post_title' => $postTitle,
    'post_content' => '$postContent,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => $current_user->ID,
    'post_type' => 'post'
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

wp_set_object_terms($post_id, array(24), 'category');
```

Comment: do you set `post_status`? it would help to see the code that inserts the post.

Comment: code sample added... the post shows up in the post listing with the category added which tells me everything I did was correct.

Comment: what does it say in the date column in the admin post list? is it Published, or possibly Scheduled?

Comment: I've experienced this too when programatically creating posts. For some reason the category/term count are not updated. I think the same goes for imports as well. See [this thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10953/fixing-category-count) for a possible explanation and solution.

Comment: @milo you hit the nail on the head. It is scheduled for 4 hours from now. Well at least now I know what's causing the issue. If only I could give you credit for pointing that out. Thanks!

Comment: Nice to see you have this one figured out:  that the post status is changed from ``publish`` to ``future``.  A quick note on this:  the term post counts will not be updated until the post status is changed from ``future`` to ``publish`` ([see this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/316777/how-to-update-incorrect-post-count-in-taxonomy/404236#404236)).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo mistake there line 3.

the code could be like this

```
    'post_content' => $postContent,
```